# Browsing not possible when Skype is running

Tags: windows, networking, browser, freeze, skype

Often I find myself in a situation where no web browsing is possible while Skype is running. Every browser page hangs or says "no data received". This occurs even when accessing local pages like `http://192.168.0.1` (control page of a router).

Simultaneously, `wget` works instantly, for example `wget http://192.168.0.1`.

If I close Skype, then regular browsing starts to work again.

This can't be Skype supernode loading, because this would affect `wget` too.

This can't be because of a glitching browser plugin, because only Internet Explorer has one installed, while Chrome hasn't, but the pages hang in Chrome too.

What can be the reason of such interference?

Comment: First **try** and disable the Skype browser plugin in IE and see if it still happens.

Comment: Yes I disabled IE plugin and will see. But glitch happens irregularly. Also how can IE plugin interfere Chrome?

Comment: Do you have other systems in your LAN? Does it affect them in any way? Most probably not, but that information would pinpoint it to be a strictly local application problem, at least.

Comment: Could this be linked to UPnP somehow ? like computers highjacking some PAT rules ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to isolate the problem, I would say start at the firewall. As far as I know Skype uses port 80 and port 443. So first, I would turn off the firewall, if it still doesnt work, then it could be isolated to maybe an anti virus agent. Try to disable the agent too. If you have isolated it to the firewall, just allow those ports to go through.